Question about Newton third law especially the reactive force
Sorry for not giving much elaboration , here is a more detailed question,I have a confusion with the reactive force in dynamic cases (not in statics). Imagine there is a box and a person (both have 10kg masses) pushing it with a force of 10N, moving the box with an acceleration of 1m/s^2 , at the same time the person will be moving with 1m/^2 ,Now for the question (assuming a smooth surface) what will be the force the person pushing the ground with , will it be 20N or 10N? Because since the box pushed the man with 10N back and he is moving with box at an acceleration of 1m/^2 ?

Don't overlook the interaction between the box and the table. Unlike your hands touching the box, it does move across the table.

Yeah i know but this question really bother me , I thought thoroughly for it and didn’t get the answer

"but not the famous question" You don't have to tell us what your question is not. Best to concentrate on telling us what your question is. Beside, I have no idea what this allegedly "famous question" is.

The famous question is most people think that the action is equal reaction and it have been answered many times so for my question to be answered and not ignored presuming it is the the most stated question about newton third so i wrote this title what is the problem?

The problem is you should try to write a clear question. See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

"he's still moving the box with the same acceleration, then he will need to be pushing harder" It is not clear what you mean by this or why you believe so. The force is simply 10 N and that's it.

Ok I edited hope it is more clear


... he (is) still moving the box with same acceleration then he will need to be pushing harder ...

If the person is still moving the box with the same acceleration then the force that the person exerts on the box is still the same. The equal and opposite reaction force that the box exerts on the person does not change the force that the person exerts on the box.
The reaction force may, however, affect the force that the person can begin to exert on the box in the first place. If the person is standing on ice, for example, while the box is on a rough surface then the reaction force will cause the person to slip backwards rather than moving the box.

So you mean like if he is moving on a rough surface will for example apply 20N on the floor and be pushing the box with only 10 N due to 10N being on the person?

@MohamedIbrahim In that scenario the net force on the person is 10N and the net force on the box is less than 10N because of friction. This is possible if the person and the box are accelerating at the same rate but the box is lighter than the person.

I need to cite JEB's Golden Rule (not as famous as Fermi's): the human body does not bring insight into mechanics.
The box pushes on the man's hands, so his skin squishes and all that.
Analyze with a mechanical equivalent: a $\frac{10}{9.82}$kg mass hangs from a rope. The rope goes over a pulley and loops around a box. (I looped to so the rope pushes the box).
The mass puts 10N of tension into the rope, the rope pushes on the box with 10N, the box puts 10N on the table.
And the table pushes on the box with 10N which pushes against the rope with 10N which puts 5N on of tension in each loop end which adds to 10N after the knot which goes over the pulley which supports the mass's weight, allowing it move at constant velocity, without acceleration caused by the 10N of gravitational force on the mass.
Of course, the mass pulls on the Earth with 10N, but since $10{\,\rm N}/M_{Earth}$ is so small, we're going to ignore that.

Thanks for the answer, i got a little bit of what you said, but now edited my question, can you read it and try answering it?

I think I know what you are confused about.
Let us first try to think about the free body diagram (the diagram which shows the object and all the forces being applied on the object in the system) in this case:

But, what you seem to be imagining it is:

Now, this confusion can arise due to how the law is stated:
"Every action has equal and opposite reaction"
Now, stating direct lines from Class 11th NCERT Physics Volume-I textbook:
Action and reaction forces act on different
bodies, not on the same body. Consider a pair
of bodies A and B. According to the third law,
FAB = – FBA (4.8)
(force on A by B) = – (force on B by A)
Thus if we are considering the motion of any
one body (A or B), only one of the two forces is
relevant. It is an error to add up the two forces
and claim that the net force is zero.

Thus, since both forces (action and reaction) occur on different objects, you can't add them up for a single object.
Hope this helps!

You are making the common mistake of thinking the reaction forces somehow “cancel” the action forces. They do not. They act on different objects.
The acceleration of the box is determined by applying Newton’s 2nd law to the box. The acceleration of the box is the net force applied to the box divided by the mass $m$ of the box. That net force is the pushing force $F$ minus the opposing kinetic (sliding) friction force, $f_k$ per the following equation
$$a=\frac{F_{net}}{m}=\frac{F-f_{k}}{m}=\frac{F-\mu_{k}mg}{m}$$
Where $\mu_k$ is the coefficient of kinetic friction.
Hope this helps

Sorry but my question seems to be a little misunderstood, u can now read it again and answer, thanks.

@MohamedIbrahim By removing the friction at the surface you have completely changed the question. At any rate, I will attempt to update my answer.

@MohamedIbrahim Just a minute. Just to be clear, are you now saying the person and the box are on a frictionless surface?

Yes mu static =0 , also there will be no slipping ( i know it is unrealistic scenario)

@MohamedIbrahim To say static friction is zero and also there will be no slipping is not only unrealistic, it makes no sense at all.

Okay I understand you , let’s say a rough surface and both the man and the person are moving with acceleration 1m/s^2 say mu kinetic = 0.5 , now what will be the the person pushing the ground, with a free-body diagram if you can , i want only to understand how the reaction affect the force the person is doing on the ground
